# WPF: Opening new window on button click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Is it possible to open a new window when a button is clicked without touching the CS code? I'd like to do something like this:

```
<Button Command="OpenNewWindow" Content="New window" />
```

or

```
<Button Command="Open NameOfMyWindow" Content="New window" />
```

I browsed through predefined commands, and found one called Open, though it doesn't seem to be designed for this task.

Comment: Are you following `MVVM`?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to learn about MVVM, so yes.

Comment: So, you better start reading on Commands in MVVM first since no inbuilt command is there to serve your purpose. You have to create your own custom command- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/274982/Commands-in-MVVM

Comment: There is no such predefined command, the only way is to create your own command. But yes, you can call this command without any cs code (as in your code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CommandParameter

```
<Button Command="OpenWindow" CommandParameter="NameOfMyWindow" Content="New window" />
```

And use that parameter in the code that handles OpenWindow command.

The generic commands are more closely associated with the typical "File" menu, you'd be opening a File or something like that. You can write a custom command for your app

Comment: I think that the question is "does predefined command, which can create window, exist?".